# I need to share data between steps in different classes

Tags: php, testing, automation, behat

I need to share data between steps in different classes using BEHAT.
Something like ([Good practice to pass variables between cucumber-jvm steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422470/good-practice-to-pass-variables-between-cucumber-jvm-steps/26434468#26434468)) PicoContainer for cucumber. Is there such a framework? I know I can use static member but maybe is some framework for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options:

1. Create a specialized class with static methods to handle different data
2. Use Behat functionality to communicate between contexts, see similar question [accessing contexts from each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674685/how-to-communicate-between-contexts-in-behat-3)
3. If you need to generate different data use Faker for php

Comment: Thank you for your response, I used 2 and everything works.